# Setup iptable with preventing ab -n 100000 -c 1000

Tags: iptables

I would like to setup basic firewall rules with iptables. The goal is to reject flood requests per IP. Like "ab -n 100000 -c 1000 "

There are only 2 rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 100/s --limit-burst 10000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -j LOG --log-prefix "__test__"
```

But I when grep iptables log with "sort" and "uniq -c" I see lot's of IPs like:

```
1 SRC=173.252.77.112
1 SRC=173.252.114.116
1 SRC=173.252.114.114
1 SRC=173.252.114.113
```

Is "-m state --state NEW" effect only new connections? Then why IPs with low requests count appeared in log?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the solution is:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m hashlimit --hashlimit 1000/sec --hashlimit-burst 5000 --hashlimit-mode dstip --hashlimit-name hosts -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

Do not block SE-crawlers packets and resists against http-flood like: ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://{host}/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the method detailed in your question just works via number of new connections per unit time without any knowledge of the IP address making the connection. In a scenario of a high volume of connections from a few IP addresses, the method is flawed because it actually increases the probability that the legitimate visitors connection will be blocked.

I use a method whereby once a "bad_guy" IP address is detected, it is banned for a day. Due to the default limits (which could be changed, but I didn't) on the recent module hit count, the method uses multiple tables with a "carry" from one to the other. Proper setup to both trigger reasonably soon for a "bad_guy" yet avoid false positives for a "good_guy" would be site specific and takes some time. First, at the normal spot in the INPUT chain:

```
# If required, go to NEW HTTP connection sub-routine
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m state --state NEW -p tcp -s $UNIVERSE -d $EXTIP --dport 80 -j http-new-in
```

And earlier in the script, I had this code:

```
#######################################################################
# USER DEFINED CHAIN SUBROUTINES:
#
# http-new-in3
#
# A NEW Connection on port 80 part 3.
#
# carry forward to the actual banned list:
# Increment this count. Leave the previous count.
#
# Custom tables must exist before being referenced, hence the order
# of these sub-toutines.
#
$IPTABLES -N http-new-in3
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in3 -m recent --remove --name HTTP_02
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in3 -m recent --update --hitcount 1 --seconds 86400 --name HTTP_BAN -j http-new-in4
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in3 -m recent --set --name HTTP_BAN

$IPTABLES -A http-new-in3 -j LOG --log-prefix "BAN80:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in3 -j DROP

#######################################################################
# USER DEFINED CHAIN SUBROUTINES:
#
# http-new-in2
#
# A NEW Connection on port 80 part 2.
#
# carry forward from previous max new connections per unit time:
# Increment this count and clear the lesser significant count.
#
$IPTABLES -N http-new-in2
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in2 -m recent --remove --name HTTP_01
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in2 -m recent --update --hitcount 3 --seconds 720 --name HTTP_02 -j http-new-in3
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in2 -m recent --set --name HTTP_02

$IPTABLES -A http-new-in2 -j LOG --log-prefix "CARRY80:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in2 -j ACCEPT

#######################################################################
# USER DEFINED CHAIN SUBROUTINES:
#
# http-new-in
#
# A NEW Connection on port 80:
#
$IPTABLES -N http-new-in

echo Allowing EXTERNAL access to the WWW server

# . check the static blacklist.
#
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -i $EXTIF -s 5.248.83.0/24 -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -i $EXTIF -s 91.200.0.0/20 -j DROP
... deleted big list of ip addresses ...
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -i $EXTIF -s 82.80.0.0/16 -j DROP

# . check the dynamic banned list
#
# The 1 Hour banned list (bumped to more than a day):
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -m recent --update --seconds 90000 --name HTTP_BAN --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "LIM80:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -m recent --update --seconds 90000 --name HTTP_BAN --rsource -j DROP

# A generic log entry. Usually only during degugging
#
#$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -j LOG --log-prefix "NEW80ALL:" --log-level info

# Dynamic Badguy List. Least significant hit counter.  Detect and DROP Bad IPs that do excessive connections to port 80.
#
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -m recent --update --hitcount 20 --seconds 240 --name HTTP_01 -j http-new-in2
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -m recent --set --name HTTP_01

$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -j LOG --log-prefix "NEW80:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A http-new-in -j ACCEPT
```

The method is adapted from this [reference](https://www.thatsgeeky.com/2011/02/escalating-consequences-with-iptables/).

Comment: Thanks for the details. This solution should be tested in each particular case. Suppose better to use 91.200.0.0/24 instead of 91.200.0.0/20. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference

Comment: @DmitryBelyaev:  Thanks for your comment. For my blacklist example, that was just one of a great many. When I get problematic stuff from a small range of IP addresses I reverse lookup the country of origin and then look up the sub-net and block the entire allocated sub-net. In this case it was Ukraine and the sub-net was 192.200.0.0/20. I do not care about collateral  damage. I use this [reference](http://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker).